# Behat for JSON API Test + Gitlab CI

Tags: laravel, gitlab-ci, behat

Can't get the GitlabCI to call the localhost (Using Guzzle) - it gives a connection refuse error.

Can't find any good resource on the subject - does anybody managed to do Behat tests for JSON Apis using Gitlab pipelines?